# How to use PSO for shortest path problem?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, particle-swarm

I'm trying to use PSO to find the shortest path between two points in a 2d grid, but I don't get, what value with, do I initialize particle velocity and fitness value. I've just learned this algorithm so, I basically don't understand how to use it in finding shortest path .

Answer (score 0):

The PSO algorithm is a stochastic optimization problem usually used on continuous problems. However, it can be used for other such problems.

The velocity should be initialized to 0, while the fitness value should be set to a very large number as you are trying to minimize it. You should start the positions of the particles within the bounds of the problem. Can you explain further the problem?

Comment: It's a 25*50 grid,  from a given cell , you can move in four directions : right, top, left, down. Cost if moving to any of the four directions is 1, now you are provided with source and destination cell, and we have to use PSO , to reach the destination from the source.

Comment: Particles initialized will be in cells top down left and right of the source.